# Should I book a place on a conference when I know I will have resigned before attending?

Tags: resignation, united-kingdom, team, expenses, exit-planning

On behalf of my current team - I have been accepted to present on our work at a research conference abroad.

The cost of the conference will  ~ $1500-$2000 once flights and expenses are accounted for. This would be covered by my employer.

The conference organisers have requested that we book on "as soon as possible". I have asked for clarification, but for the purposes of this question, let's assume they mean within the next week.

I am planning to resign before the conference date, but not necessarily before the conference "book on" date. I am currently not ready to submit my resignation and probably will have to book the conference before.

If I know I will not be able to attend, am I obligated to *not* book this course? What do I owe my employer in this scenario?

Other information: My team has 3 other members, one of which could potentially take my place on the conference.

Comment: Just book transferable tickets or with a minor cancel fee.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I am planning to resign before the conference date, but not necessarily before the conference "book on" date. I am currently not ready to submit my resignation and probably will have to book the conference before.

If you're not ready today, there's no guarantee you'll be ready then. In which case, the usual advice applies in these situations: Continue at work as though you have no intention of going anywhere.

Answer (score 7):

> My team has 3 other members, one of which could potentially take my place on the conference.

This makes it easy. Book the conference, and if you do happen to leave then someone else on the team can go.

Comment: Tickets are most likely counted towards this specific person though, let alone the rest of the team may have plans of their own if notified at a short notice. Accounting for another team member to take their place from the get-go seems the most logical thing to do to not alienate anyone and neither disgruntle the company either.

Comment: @Leon most conferences are okay with changing the name on the ticket, if they even care. Just this year I've been to one conference on a ticket changed at last notice _and_ a conference on somebody else's ticket (because they already went for day 1 and couldn't make day 2).

Comment: @Erik flights may not be as flexible to changes though so all in all to save the last minute hassle for the company manager as well as not incurring additional costs an internal substitution from the get-go seems the most appropriate thing to do.

Answer (score -1):

Consider speaking with a team member to get substituted and not-accounted for beforehand.

This way you won't be bound to this obligation by any means and the company wont have booked flights and accommodation that they 'll have to change(which may not even be possible at the time) or have to scramble at the last minute to find a replacement for you to attend.

**EDIT:** since apparently some people misunderstood this, I suggest to be tactful about this and quote personal reasons as to why you cant make it. No need to inform your co-workers of your intention to resign.

Comment: Speaking to someone else at your place of employment about your intent to resign before you've made the decision to resign is not a very good idea.

Comment: @GOATNine except you can be tactful about it and quote personal reasons as to why you cannot make it, no need to say anything further than this.